# Check if purchase is valid then Reward

Tags: java, android, firebase, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in app purchase in my app . But it's rewarding user without purchase . Can anyone help me to solve the issue? I have used base64 key to check the purchase is valid or not still getting this bug {User is getting reward but in my console there is no order history.}. This is very complicated that's why i am asking if any expert help me to solve this.

Here i am consuming purchase and rewarding user.

```
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
            && purchases != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {

            if (verifyValidSignature(purchase.getOriginalJson(), purchase.getSignature())) {
               handlePurchase(purchase);
                consumePurchase(purchase);
            }
        }
    }
}

boolean thatThingHappened = false;
private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {

    switch (purchase.getSku()) {
        case ITEM_S: {
            if (purchase.getPurchaseToken()!=null){    

                if (!thatThingHappened){
                    thatThingHappened = true;
                    //reward the user

                    /*incrementCoins(2000); */

                    //In database i am getting this and it has been more than 15 without any purchase
                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    rootRef.child("Purchase").push().child(Uid).setValue(2000);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private boolean verifyValidSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
    return Security.verifyPurchase(getString(R.string.base64Key), signedData, signature);
}
```

Comment: "still getting this bug"... what bug?

Comment: have you tried step-by-step debugging?

Comment: Giving user reward without purchase. i have added this line in my code with this // .

Comment: Yes i have checked with test purchase, from my side it's working but when i put it on play store , User is getting reward but in my console there is no order history.